# Local domain and sub domain mapping (web development)

Tags: java, linux, google-app-engine, fedora

Under Linux what are the options for implementing a domain and subdomain mapping for a Google App Engine web application during development mode.

- Is there like a on-the-fly domain mapping where I don't have to deal with modifying Linux network properties manually?

I have a GAE where the I need to make this subdomain mapping based on some hash or username like:

`http://username.myapp.com` (Local)

Where it is also accessible through `http://myapp.com/username`

Right now I can access such resource through: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/somename`

However, right now I really need to test it with such mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to test it locally by defining the subdomains in your hosts file, `/etc/hosts` (unix/linux)  or `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. So, for example, you could define there

```
127.0.0.1 myapp.com subdomain1.myapp.com subdomain2.myapp.com
```

And then going on your browser to either of these domain names will go to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that the domain mapping is static, I need something that is dynamic, that is, the access to user1.mydomain.com will be translated into mydomain.com/user1

Comment: Seems you'd have to set up a DNS server... However this needn't be too difficult, you for example see http://serverfault.com/questions/118378/in-my-etc-hosts-file-on-linux-osx-how-do-i-do-a-wildcard-subdomain